# Vertex colors not working properly

Tags: c++, directx, direct3d, directx-11

I'm trying out direct3D, so I drew some triangles, this worked fine and it drew 3 yellow triangles.

But now I'm trying to make triangles where every vertex has a different color and has interpolation of colors within the triangle. What got displayed on the screen instead were 3 triangles of every side of the triangle has a different color, but within the triangle everything is white.

I left some code out of which I think it's irrelevant to the problem, if there is a function where you think the problem could be, just ask and I'll edit the post.

This is what I get, you can see that only the side of the triangles get a color:
http://puu.sh/kzuSn/4c8d0b01f0.png

This is the code I use to create the triangles.

cpp file:

```
#include "TrianglePosCol2D.h"

struct VertexPosCol
{
    XMFLOAT3 Position;
    XMFLOAT4 Color;
};

TrianglePosCol2D::TrianglePosCol2D(ID3D11Device* pD3DDevice)
    :m_pD3DDevice(pD3DDevice)
    ,m_pVertexLayout(nullptr)
    ,m_pVertexBuffer(nullptr)
    ,m_pEffect(nullptr)
    ,m_pTechnique(nullptr)
    ,m_NumVertices(0)
{

}

TrianglePosCol2D::~TrianglePosCol2D(void)
{
    if( m_pVertexBuffer )   m_pVertexBuffer->Release();
    if( m_pVertexLayout)    m_pVertexLayout->Release();
    if( m_pEffect )         m_pEffect->Release();
}

HRESULT TrianglePosCol2D::Create(XMFLOAT3 p1, XMFLOAT3 p2, XMFLOAT3 p3, XMFLOAT4 c1, XMFLOAT4 c2, XMFLOAT4 c3)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Compile the vertex shader
    BuildEffect();

    // Define the input layout
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC inputDesc[] =
    {
        { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "COLOR", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT,0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0}
    };
    UINT numElements = sizeof(inputDesc) / sizeof(inputDesc[0]);

    // Create the input layout
    D3DX11_PASS_DESC passDesc = { 0 };
    m_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(0)->GetDesc(&passDesc);
    hr = m_pD3DDevice->CreateInputLayout(
        inputDesc,
        numElements,
        passDesc.pIAInputSignature,
        passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize,
        &m_pVertexLayout);

    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    // Create vertex buffer
    m_NumVertices = 3;
    //VertexPosCol vertices[] = { (p1,p2,p3),(c1,c2,c3)};
    VertexPosCol vertices[] = { { p1,c1 }, { p2,c2 }, { p3,c3 } };


    //vertices.Position = (p1, p2, p3);
    //vertices.Color = (c1, c2, c3);

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc = { 0 };
    bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(vertices)*m_NumVertices;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA initData = { 0 };
    initData.pSysMem = &vertices[0];

    hr = m_pD3DDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &initData, &m_pVertexBuffer);

    return hr;
}

void TrianglePosCol2D::Paint(ID3D11DeviceContext* pDeviceContext)
{
    // Set the input layout
    pDeviceContext->IASetInputLayout(m_pVertexLayout);

    // Set vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof(VertexPosCol);
    UINT offset = 0;
    pDeviceContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_pVertexBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    // Set primitive topology
    pDeviceContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // Render a triangle
    D3DX11_TECHNIQUE_DESC techDesc;
    m_pTechnique->GetDesc(&techDesc);
    for (UINT p = 0; p <techDesc.Passes; ++p)
    {
        m_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0, pDeviceContext);
        pDeviceContext->Draw(m_NumVertices, 0);
    }

}
```

And this is the code used for creating the triangles.

```
HRESULT GP2_RenderingPipeline::GameInitialize()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    m_pColoredTriangle1 = new TrianglePosCol2D(m_pDevice);
    hr = m_pColoredTriangle1->Create(XMFLOAT3(-1.f, -1.f, 0.99f), XMFLOAT3(-1.f, 1.f, 0.99f), XMFLOAT3(0.f, 1.f, 0.99f), XMFLOAT4(255.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f), XMFLOAT4(0.f, 255.f, 0.f, 0.f), XMFLOAT4(0.f, 0.f, 255.f, 0.f));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Create TrianglePos2D failed!", L"DirectX says NO", MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(-1);
    }

    m_pColoredTriangle2 = new TrianglePosCol2D(m_pDevice);
    hr = m_pColoredTriangle2->Create(XMFLOAT3(-0.5f, 0.f, 0.99f), XMFLOAT3(0.5f, 0.f, .99f), XMFLOAT3(0.f, -1.f, 0.99f), XMFLOAT4(255.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f), XMFLOAT4(0.f, 255.f, 0.f, 0.f), XMFLOAT4(0.f, 0.f, 255.f, 0.f));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Create TrianglePos2D failed!", L"DirectX says NO", MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(-1);
    }

    m_pColoredTriangle3 = new TrianglePosCol2D(m_pDevice);
    hr = m_pColoredTriangle3->Create(XMFLOAT3(0.f, 1.f, 0.99f), XMFLOAT3(1.f, 1.f, 0.99f), XMFLOAT3(1.f, -1.f, 0.99f), XMFLOAT4(255.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f), XMFLOAT4(0.f, 255.f, 0.f, 0.f), XMFLOAT4(0.f, 0.f, 255.f, 0.f));
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(nullptr, L"Create TrianglePos2D failed!", L"DirectX says NO", MB_ABORTRETRYIGNORE | MB_ICONERROR);
        exit(-1);
    }

    return S_OK;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess, you are outputting the interpolated vertex color from the pixel shader. Then, your problem is the range.

DirectX usually uses colors in the range `[0, 1]`. Everything above or below that is clipped to the range bounds. On the edges, you interpolate between colors where the components are disjoint (e.g. `(255, 0, 0)` and `(0, 255, 0)`). This will result in something that is greater than 1 in the first two components and zero in the third component for almost every pixel. I.e. the resulting color (after clipping) is `(1, 1, 0)`. Inside a triangle, every component is greater than 1, so you see white.

Long story short: Reduce the color range from `[0, 255]` to `[0, 1]`.

Comment: I'll try it out, thank you so much :D It's always simple mistakes that make me browse for an answer for hours.

Comment: How do I accept? I can't seem to find an option for it :s

Comment: @user3678781 - check the checkmark. and select the up arrow if you found the answer to be especially useful (or a good answer in general).